# Studying electronics and programming in Austria

Tags: student-motivation, student-perceptions

I'm planning to start university next year. I'd like to study programming and electronics, and one of the countries I'm considering for my education is Austria.

Which university in Austria can you recommend for studying programming and electronics?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can hardly study _programming_. There may be degrees in _Informatik_ which is closer to _computer science_ in the anglo world. That said, you will do a lot of prgramming in the pursuit of said degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. First, you should decide whether you would like to study at a university or a "university of applied sciences" (FH).

FHs are more like schools. You have a fixed schedule, you are part of a (relatively small) class and the focus is more on actually doing the stuff you learn about. The teachers are often not scientists but professionals of this field.

On universities on the other hand, you usually need to take care about your which courses you take and you decide how much time you want to spend on the studies. The teachers are often scientists and the contents of the courses is often more about how things work and not only how to apply them.

There are three technical universities in Austria. Most well known are the TU Wien (Vienna) and the TU Graz, the third one is the JKU (Linz). You need to decide if you want to live in a big city like Vienna or prefer smaller cities like Graz or Linz.

Do you speak German? As far as I've seen, the Computer Science Bachelor's programme at the TU Wien is German only. For Graz and Linz I found info that "many courses are offered in English". But this means not all are offered in English.

At the FHs, there are some programmes offered in English: [https://www.fachhochschulen.ac.at/...](https://www.fachhochschulen.ac.at/studiengaenge?tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=studyarea%3ATechnik&tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B1%5D=studyareasub%3AInformatik&tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B2%5D=language%3AEnglisch)